# Regular expression to extract a specific string from a given string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am having a string like: `"abc xyz: ID# 1000123, this is test, test 1, test 1234, "`

I need to write a regular expression to extract the ID `1000123`.

I have tried some thing like:

```
Regex betweenOfRegexCompiled = new Regex("ID# (.*), ", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

But it gives "1000123, this is test, test 1, test 1234".

So, how to specify the first occurrence of the `", "` ?

Comment: Change `"ID# (.*), "` to `"ID# (.*?), "`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ AgentFire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gets the number (i.e. all chars up to, but not including, the first comma) ...

```
"ID# ([^,]*),"
```

If you want to make it **numbers explicity** then...

```
"ID# ([0-9]*),"
```

For a **non-regex version** ...

```
string text = "abc xyz: ID# 1000123, this is test, test 1, test 1234, ";
string num = text.Split(new Char[] {','})[0].Split(new Char[] {' '})[3];
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `.*` use `\d+`:

```
"ID# (\d+)"
```

The `.*` matches any number of characters. `\d+` matches one or more numerals (if you want to exclude non western numerals, use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`).

Answer (score 3):

Here's the (more efficient) non-Regex approach:

```
string text = "abc xyz: ID# 1000123, this is test, test 1, test 1234, ";
string id = null;
int idIndex = text.IndexOf("ID# ");
if(idIndex != -1)
{
    idIndex += "ID# ".Length;
    int commaIndex = text.IndexOf(',', idIndex);
    if(commaIndex != -1)
        id = text.Substring(idIndex, commaIndex - idIndex);
    else
        id = text.Substring(idIndex);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/yO2gq7)

Comment: Nice example usage of Ideone

Answer (score 2):

Try this reg, it should take exactly the number

```
(?<=ID\#\s)\d+(?=\,)
```

if finds the number after **ID#** and before **,**